# Kohana 3.3 and Phpunit test cmd line Without Minion mod

Tags: php, phpunit, command-line-interface, kohana-3.3

I am trying to get Phpunit command line to work Kohana 3.3.1 and Php, but it's giving this error:

> Please enable the Minion module for CLI support.

I do not want to do this as Phpunit test works fine via the GUI.

phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="../../index.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Kohana Tests">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Sample Test class:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

class SampleTest extends Kohana_Unittest_TestCase {
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $post = array();

        $username = Arr::get($post, 'username');

        $this->assertEquals($username, null);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to run phpunit via cmd line without using Minion? If so how?